# Not able to get data from model class to buildContext in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not able to get uid from User model class, so what I am doing is adding uid using postRequest method in loginScreen Class and it successfuly adds uid data to user model class and it shows that also in that postRest method but when I try to access it in context block it shows **null**
below is my loginScreen class where I have defined postRequest method,

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:./model/user.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:./screens/secret_screen.dart';
import 'package:./screens/signup.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

final password = TextEditingController();
User user = User();

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final email = TextEditingController();
  bool? isEmailValid;
  final password = TextEditingController();
  bool? isPassworddValid;
  bool _passwordVisible = false;

  postRequest(email, password) async {
    var url = Uri.parse("http://myApiIpHere/login");
    Map data = {"email": email.text, "password": password.text};
    //encode Map to JSON
    var body = json.encode(data);
    var response = await http.post(url,
        headers: {
          "accept": "application/json",
          "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        body: body);
    var res = json.decode(response.body);
     // below uid is assigned to user model var uid and it prints properly also 
    user.uid = res["uid"];

    print("uid is ${user.uid}");

    if (user.uid == null)
      print("------uid isss null");
    else
      print("------uis is properly assinged ");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("uid - ${user!.uid}");
    // but in above print statement its not printing uid from model class
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        body: Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Expanded(
            child: Image.asset(
              height: size.height * 1,
              'assets/images/login.jpg',
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          //<-- Expanded widget
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            // constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 21),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: size.width * 0.1, vertical: size.height * 0.05),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: size.width * 0.3,
                    height: size.height * 0.1,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/logo1.jpg',
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 25),
                  Text(
                    'Welcome back',
                    style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 8),
                  Text(
                    'Login to your account',
                    style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                      fontSize: 23,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 35),
                  const Padding(
                      child: Text(
                        'Email',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10)),
                  TextField(
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {});
                      // print(val);
                    },
                    cursorColor: Colors.black,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    cursorHeight: 30,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    maxLength: 30,
                    cursorWidth: 1,
                    controller: email,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.0),
                      ),
                      focusColor: Colors.white,
                      fillColor: Colors.white30,
                      filled: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                      child: Text(
                        'Password',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10)),
                  TextField(
                    obscureText: !_passwordVisible,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {});
                      // print(val);
                    },
                    cursorColor: Colors.black,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    cursorHeight: 30,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    maxLength: 30,
                    cursorWidth: 1,
                    controller: password,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
                          });
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          _passwordVisible
                              ? Icons.remove_red_eye
                              : Icons.visibility_off,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.0),
                      ),
                      focusColor: Colors.white,
                      fillColor: Colors.white30,
                      filled: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                      child: Text(
                        'Forgot password?',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2)),
                  const SizedBox(height: 25),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          fixedSize: const Size(100, 50),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        setState(() {
                          user!.uid;
                          print("setstate ${user!.uid}");
                        });
                        final SharedPreferences sp =
                            await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                        sp.setString("email", email.text);
                        sp.setString("password", password.text);
                        try {
                          postRequest(email, password);
                        } catch (e) {
                          print("$e  is your error");
                        }
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                SecretScreen(uid: user!.uid!)));
                      },
                      child: const Text('Login now')),
                  const SizedBox(height: 25),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

my model class is,

```
import 'dart:convert';

User userFromJson(String str) => User.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userToJson(User data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class User {
  User({
     this.email,
     this.password,
     this.accessCode,
     this.uid,
     this.secretToken,
  });
  String? uid;
  String? email;
  String? password;
  String? accessCode;
  String? secretToken;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        email: json["email"],
        uid: json["uid"],
        password: json["password"],
        accessCode: json["access_code"],
        secretToken: json["secret_token"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "email": email,
        "uid":uid,
        "password": password,
        "access_code": accessCode,
        "secret_token": secretToken,
      };
}
```

I tried created another instance of User model in context but that too didnt worked

Comment: postRequest is an async function. You cannot expect the user.uid to be non-null, because it is still not available.

Comment: wait until the future is completed.

Answer (score 0):

```
  // below uid is assigned to user model var uid and it prints properly also 
user.uid = res["uid"];
```

print("uid - ${user!.uid}");
// but in above print statement its not printing uid from model class

1. Because you get a user ID after clicking login-now button and calling API and also the buildMethod is run first when the screen is initialize that's why you get null value inside uid in buildMethod.
2. You made a User object as global that's ok but do not create another user object other wise it will empty all the value.
3. The other thing is that you can use setState after calling API inside LoginNow button so you can see UID in buildMethod just try given code below for your staisfaction.

I just comment screen route and put await beside postRequest

```
 ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          fixedSize: const Size(100, 50),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        setState(() {
                          user!.uid;
                          print("setstate ${user!.uid}");
                        });
                        final SharedPreferences sp =
                            await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                        sp.setString("email", email.text);
                        sp.setString("password", password.text);
                        try {
                          await postRequest(email, password);
                          setState(() {
                            
                          });
                        } catch (e) {
                          print("$e  is your error");
                        }
                        // Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        //     builder: (context) =>
                        //         SecretScreen(uid: user!.uid!)));
                      },
                      child: const Text('Login now')),
```